# Why an IF block is allowed inside another IF that doesn't have curly brackets in JAVA

Tags: java, if-statement, brackets

Normally in JAVA if an IF statement doesn't have curly brackets can have only one line that is executed when IF condition is met, however if another IF block (inner IF) follows the initial IF, then no error is triggered and there are more lines. How is this possible?

Example

```
if (true)
if (true)
   System.out.println("true");
else
   System.out.println("false");
```

Comment: good read http://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/ControlFlow/nested-if.html

Comment: Java IS NOT WRITTEN IN CAPITAL CHARACTERS, but with only one captical, like this: Java. :)

Comment: very first statement after if will consider in if's body

Comment: related to [1-line IF statements in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504003/1-line-if-statements-in-java) and with in one minute i got zillions of result on Google for that and this [The if Statement](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c3/s5.html) would be  best answer every

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. Very good feedbacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Normally in JAVA if an IF statement doesn't have curly brackets can have only one line that is executed when IF condition is met,

Correction.  An `if` statement without braces can have only one *statement* that is executed when the condition is met.  And the syntax of `if` goes something like

```
if (<condition>) <statement>; [else <statement>;]
```

That is, if there's an `else`, it's part of the `if`.  It's all one statement.

The reason there's no error is because there's no ambiguity here.  (Well, not to the compiler, anyway.)  Since the `else` is part of the `if`, it goes with the closest `if`.  So with proper indenting, you have

```
if (true)
    if (true)
       System.out.println("true");
    else
       System.out.println("false");
```

Answer (score 5):

No errors because it equals to

```
if (true) {
    if (true) {
       System.out.println("true");
    }
    else
    {
       System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

And a valid syntax.

But please always use  `{}`  otherwise, it's very hard to understand where the `if` block ends exactly.

Comment: +1 I suggest you always use standard indentation or use you IDE to do it for you.  That way you can clearly see the nesting even if you don't have `{ }`

Comment: if (true) int x=0; int y=0; is identical with if (true) {int x=0; int y=0;} and still returns an error.

Comment: @Alin Which error you got ??

Comment: I get an error if I put an else after the 2 statements, while using curly braces I don't. If I don't have an if, int y=0; it will not be executed as part of the if block.

Comment: I'm not sure,what I understood is, now you are facing some scoping of local variables issue,And also one of the main reason is to always use `{}`

Comment: No. You are saying that if(true) if(true) System.out.println("true"); else System.out.println("false"); doesn't return an error because can be translated in statements with braces. But having if(true) if(true) System.out.println("true1"); System.out.println("true2"); else System.out.println("false"); can also be translated in statement with braces, but compiler is complaining, so having the translation possible is not the reason why is working. Hope this clarify. I used variables because prints are longer and code isn't very readable in comments. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's because your outer `if` block really contains a single statement.

- If inner `if` condition is true, the outer `if` is equivalent to:

  ```
  if (true)
      System.out.println("true");
  ```
- And if, inner `if` condition if `false`, it is equivalent to:

  ```
  if (true)
      System.out.println("false");
  ```

Still, it is *really a bad idea to omit the curly braces* around `if-else` or loops for that matter, and specially doing this with nested block, can turn evil. Just because it can be done, doesn't mean you should do it.

To see how the nested `if` blocks without braces can grow ugly, and often lead to mistakes, consider this code, what do you think the output should be?

```
boolean b = true;
boolean b2 = false;

if (b)
    if (true)
       System.out.println("true");
       if (b2)
           System.out.println("Hello");
else
    System.out.println("false");
```

Answer (score 0):

consider this IF statement as:

```
    if(true) {
       if(true) {
           System.out.println("true"); 
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("false");
       }
    }
```

if first `IF` is `true` it goes to next statement, here next statement is also a `IF`  and also `true` therefore it executes statements in it. If suppose it is false then it search for `else` end executes statements in `else`. So all statement are got covered and no error scenario occurs.